# Apache Kylin and Sqoop - Is there a way to edit the Sqoop generated SQL statement?

Tags: sqoop, kylin

I am working with Apache Kylin and using Sqoop to connect to my PostgreSQL database. I have a cube created based on a fact table that references the same dimensional table twice. So the problem arises when I try to build the cube, I get the following error on the first step of the job (#1 Step Name: Sqoop To Flat Hive Table):

```
ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: table name "d_date" specified more than once
```

The problem is that Sqoop generates SQL and references the table d_date twice and gives it the same alias both times so the SQL statement fails... Can I configure it in any way to fix this issue?

Edit: If the answer is no, that is also helpful, I just really need to know whether there is anything I can do to fix this...

This is the generated SQL (bold is where the problem is):

SELECT f_exam.course_id as F_EXAM_COURSE_ID ,f_exam.academic_year_id as F_EXAM_ACADEMIC_YEAR_ID ,f_exam.semester_id as F_EXAM_SEMESTER_ID ,f_exam.exam_id as F_EXAM_EXAM_ID ,f_exam.exam_app_user_created_id as F_EXAM_EXAM_APP_USER_CREATED_ID ,f_exam.exam_available_from_date_id ,f_exam.exam_available_from_time_id as F_EXAM_EXAM_AVAILABLE_FROM_TIME_ID ,f_exam.exam_available_to_date_id as F_EXAM_EXAM_AVAILABLE_TO_DATE_ID ,f_exam.exam_available_to_time_id as F_EXAM_EXAM_AVAILABLE_TO_TIME_ID ,f_exam.exam_ordinal_id as F_EXAM_EXAM_ORDINAL_ID ,d_time_day.time_day_id as D_AVAILABLE_FROM_TIME_TIME_DAY_ID ,d_time_day.hour_minutes_seconds as D_AVAILABLE_FROM_TIME_HOUR_MINUTES_SECONDS ,d_time_day.the_seconds as D_AVAILABLE_FROM_TIME_THE_SECONDS ,d_time_day.the_minutes as D_AVAILABLE_FROM_TIME_THE_MINUTES ,d_time_day.the_hours as D_AVAILABLE_FROM_TIME_THE_HOURS ,d_time_day.period_of_day as D_AVAILABLE_FROM_TIME_PERIOD_OF_DAY ,d_time_day.time_day_id as D_AVAILABLE_TO_TIME_TIME_DAY_ID ,d_time_day.hour_minutes_seconds as D_AVAILABLE_TO_TIME_HOUR_MINUTES_SECONDS ,d_time_day.the_seconds as D_AVAILABLE_TO_TIME_THE_SECONDS ,d_time_day.the_minutes as D_AVAILABLE_TO_TIME_THE_MINUTES ,d_time_day.the_hours as D_AVAILABLE_TO_TIME_THE_HOURS ,d_time_day.period_of_day as D_AVAILABLE_TO_TIME_PERIOD_OF_DAY ,f_exam.number_of_questions as F_EXAM_NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS ,f_exam.duration_in_seconds as F_EXAM_DURATION_IN_SECONDS ,f_exam.number_of_students_participated as F_EXAM_NUMBER_OF_STUDENTS_PARTICIPATED ,f_exam.is_forward_only_01 as F_EXAM_IS_FORWARD_ONLY_01 ,f_exam.max_score_possible as F_EXAM_MAX_SCORE_POSSIBLE ,f_exam.max_score as F_EXAM_MAX_SCORE ,f_exam.min_score as F_EXAM_MIN_SCORE ,f_exam.pass_percentage as F_EXAM_PASS_PERCENTAGE ,f_exam.max_score_percentage as F_EXAM_MAX_SCORE_PERCENTAGE ,f_exam.min_score_percentage as F_EXAM_MIN_SCORE_PERCENTAGE ,f_exam.avg_score as F_EXAM_AVG_SCORE ,f_exam.median as F_EXAM_MEDIAN ,f_exam.first_quartile as F_EXAM_FIRST_QUARTILE ,f_exam.third_quartile as F_EXAM_THIRD_QUARTILE ,f_exam.interquartile_range as F_EXAM_INTERQUARTILE_RANGE ,f_exam.minimum_without_outliers as F_EXAM_MINIMUM_WITHOUT_OUTLIERS ,f_exam.maximum_without_outliers as F_EXAM_MAXIMUM_WITHOUT_OUTLIERS  FROM public.f_exam f_exam INNER JOIN public.d_course d_course ON f_exam.course_id = d_course.course_id INNER JOIN public.d_academic_year d_academic_year ON f_exam.academic_year_id = d_academic_year.academic_year_id INNER JOIN public.d_semester d_semester ON f_exam.semester_id = d_semester.semester_id INNER JOIN public.d_exam d_exam ON f_exam.exam_id = d_exam.exam_id INNER JOIN public.d_app_user d_app_user ON f_exam.exam_app_user_created_id = d_app_user.app_user_id **INNER JOIN public.d_date d_date ON f_exam.exam_available_from_date_id = d_date.date_id** INNER JOIN public.d_time_day d_time_day ON f_exam.exam_available_from_time_id = d_time_day.time_day_id **INNER JOIN public.d_date d_date ON f_exam.exam_available_to_date_id = d_date.date_id** INNER JOIN public.d_time_day d_time_day ON f_exam.exam_available_to_time_id = d_time_day.time_day_id INNER JOIN public.d_ordinal d_ordinal ON f_exam.exam_ordinal_id = d_ordinal.ordinal_id WHERE 1=1 AND (f_exam.exam_available_from_date_id >= 20120101 AND f_exam.exam_available_from_date_id < 20170101)  AND  (1 = 0)

Comment: can you explain how you installed sqoop? maybe i try to reproduce it using sql server. On the other hand in kylin when joining you can give different alias on the tables but not sure what is happening in sqoop.

Answer (score 0):

The long long SQL is generated by Kylin and submitted to sqoop for execution. So you really need is to fix the duplicated alias of the two `public.d_date d` tables in Kylin model definition.

In Kylin model designer, around your fact table `f_exam`, there must be two `public.d_date d`. Set their alias to different names, save the model and try build again. This shall change the generated SQL and let the sqoop step pass.